# Is it best practice to put handler thread classes in the fragment or activity class?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm currently attempting to convert my existing Android app to using Fragments. The main work that my activity does can sometimes take a while, so I implemented some Threads to act as callback handlers - I was led to believe this is best practice to use these and a progress dialog.

Hopefully that makes sense.

My question is: should I move those inner classes to my Fragment class, or keep them in my Activity class?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the best practice for software in general is a little different, first of all you need to know that there's no "Hard Rules" to anything in software, the keyword is "All Depends(Taken from book Pragmatic Thinking and Learning)" and as such, it all depends on what you want and what you need, you should put things on a balance to know where is better for you, but going back to the best practice in general for these cases the best is to have a Business Model Class completely decoupled from either Fragment/Activity or any other android component, you are actually supposed to have a Model Class and together with a Controller Class, both of them should manipulate/populate the data and views within those elements...

Hope this helps.

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

That depends how many fragments you have and what you're trying to do with those threads. While there is no general rule, here are two things to consider in making your decision.

(1) If you're doing something like downloading information that's going to be used in multiple fragments (say in a `ViewPager` or `Tab` set up) it might make sense to have the callbacks in your `FragmentActivity` this way you can easly distribute that information to the `Fragment` that will be handling the UI. Another example that comes to mind would be fetching location data. If the location data is going to be used throughout the app, and your `FragmentActivity` is hosting multiple fragments, it makes more sense to get the information in one place and simply update the fragments individually.

(2) If you're using something like `AsyncTask` for one-off downloads, posts, or other things unique to a specific fragment, there's nothing wrong with keeping it localized to that fragment. In fact, in that case, it would be less efficient to off load the task to your `FragmentActivity` than to complete the task localy.

Really there's not "right" answer. Just a question of how your app is structured and what you're trying to acomplish.

Answer (score 0):

There's no hard and fast rule, but I like keep them in the scope within which they most naturally fit. If the result of a long running task is only useful within the fragment which initiated it then it lives in the fragment. If the task may affect multiple fragments then it might live in the activity.